# Biblatex: multiple citation numbers all within same bracket with the ieee style

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm using the `ieee` style for `biblatex` and when inserting citations I want

> [1,2,6-10]

Right now I'm getting

> [1],[2],[6-10].

How can I change this?

Comment: How do you cite? \parencite[citation1], \parencite[citation2]... or \parencite[citation1, citation2, citation3...]

Comment: Do you mean "I want [1,2,6-10]"?

Comment: The IEEE 'house style' is to include those square brackets deliberately around each number (the `biblatex` style simply follows `ieeetran` in this regard). Are you submitting to the IEEE?

Comment: @JosephWright No, it's for my PhD.

Comment: @Chris I'm using \cite{}\cite{}

Comment: @jlanza try putting them into one cite command `cite{ref1, ref2...}`

Comment: @Chris when I did that what I got is what was reflected in the post ([1],[2],[6-10])

Comment: How to do the opposite. I want [11],[16] but getting [11-16] in the IEEE format

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be OK by simply using the `ieee` style for the bibliography but the standard `numeric-comp` for the citations. For example

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{IEEEexample:bookwitheditor,
  editor        = "J. C. Candy and G. C. Temes",
  title         = "Oversampling Delta-Sigma Data Converters Theory,
                   Design and Simulation",
  publisher     = "{IEEE} Press.",
  location      = "New York",
  year          = "1992"
}

@article{IEEEexample:articlelargepages,
  author        = "A. Castaldini and A. Cavallini and B. Fraboni
                   and P. Fernandez and J. Piqueras",
  title         = "Midgap Traps Related to Compensation Processes in
                   {CdTe} Alloys",
  journaltitle  = "Phys. Rev. B.",
  volume        = "56",
  number        = "23",
  year          = "1997",
  pages         = "14897-14900"
}

@article{IEEEexample:TBPmisc,
  author        = "M. Coates and A. Hero and R. Nowak and B. Yu",
  title         = "Internet Tomography",
  journaltitle  = "IEEE J. Selected Areas Commun.",
  month         = 05,
  year          = "2002",
  note          = "to be published"
}
\end{filecontents*}•

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibstyle=ieee,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\cite{IEEEexample:bookwitheditor, IEEEexample:TBPmisc, IEEEexample:articlelargepages}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(I've included some bibliography data purely to create a self-contained demo.)

Notice that for citations that should be bracketed together, compressed into a range and so on you should use one `\cite` command and a comma-list of keys within the argument.

Comment: `bibstyle=ieee` must come before `citestyle=numeric-comp` also, or it doesn't work. (Or so it was for me.)

Answer (score 3):

> Note that this answer is only for non-`biblatex` users, since `biblatex` is
>   incompatible with the `cite` package! Thanks to @moewe for pointing that out.

What worked for me is simply adding

```
\renewcommand\citepunct{, }
```

to the preamble, as hinted in the [cite.sty](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cite/cite.pdf) package documentation.

Here is a screenshot of the result

Before: [image]
After: [image]

But note that I just tested this in conjunction with

```
\documentclass[10pt,final,journal,compsoc,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
```

Comment: In particular this answer will not work with `biblatex` (which is what the OP is using), since `cite` and `biblatex` are incompatible.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @moewe! Since this approach might work for others (including me) I'd still prefer to let this info stay here.

Comment: Fair enough. Since the question is very clear that it is about `biblatex` I consider it unlikely that those not using `biblatex` would look at this question, but an alternative approach probably does not do any harm as long as it is pointed out cleraly that this approach here is indeed not compatible with `biblatex` (and thus the premise of the question) at all and assumes a different underlying setup.

Comment: Well, at least one found the question via google and looked at it, not using biblatex :) Thanks again.