# Biblatex references "[1,2]" instead of "[1], [2]"

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I use `biblatex` with IEEE-style. For `\cite{key1, key2}` I now get

> [1], [2]

How can I override this (so that only this behaviour changes) to get as output

> [1,2]

**EDIT: The nicest solution (in my opinion) is mentioned in the link posted by Joseph (using citestyle):**

Change (in case of class):

```
\RequirePackage[(...),style=ieee]{biblatex}
```

to:

```
\RequirePackage[(...),style=ieee,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
```

Comment: The `ieee` style quite deliberately does this as that's what the IEEE do!

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191418/biblatex-multiple-citation-numbers-all-within-same-bracket-with-tthe-ieee-style

Comment: Thanks Joseph Wright. This is the nicest solution: \RequirePackage[(...),style=ieee,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution, overwriting the `ieee` cite style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee, citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}

Text text text \cites{knuth:ct:c, companion, knuth:ct:d, knuth:ct:a}

More text \cites{ knuth:ct:b, knuth:ct:a, companion}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]