# How to replace multiple references by an en-dash in a citation using Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to cite a couple of authors for the same thing using `biblatex`. What I get is something like this:

> [21,22,23,24,25]

Instead I want it to look like this:

> [21-25]

For BibTeX my research revealed that I should use the package `cite`, but that isn't compatible with `biblatex`. I guess there is an easy way for `biblatex` as well but I just can't find it. Thanks for your help in advance!

Edit: I am using `bibstyle=ieee`, maybe it's a style setting?

Comment: Off-topic: This connector may look like a hyphen, but it's not.  It's an en-dash, which is to be used to indicate a span (pages, dates, references, ...).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191418/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/439086/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191418/35864.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed a property of the selected style.

---

By default `biblatex-ieee` compresses multiple citations, but the brackets look a bit differently from what you describe in the question.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ieee, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [1]–[4]]

---

If you want the brackets as described in the question, you can set the `citestyle` to `numeric-comp`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ieee, citestyle=numeric-comp, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [1–4]]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Somehow by default I get what I stated above and not your version but numeric-comp is working fine.