# IEEEtran conference class won't let me put multiple citations into 1 bracket with BibTex

Tags: ieeetran, cite-package, multiple-citations

First post here so I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong, but here it goes:

Like [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191418/biblatex-multiple-citation-numbers-all-within-same-bracket-with-the-ieee-style), I seem to struggle with putting multiple citations into the same brackets. The solution that's presented

```
\renewcommand\citepunct{, }
```

only works for 2 citations. If I add more it still does it like this:

> [1]-[3]

In the ieeetran documentation it states that if the "cite" package is used, this should be fixed, however I am using the cite package and it still does not work. How do I get this to work?

Im using BibTex and work in overleaf btw.

Example code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
\cite{dummy1,dummy2,dummy3}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

Will result in:

> [1]-[3]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to suggest that you switch from using the `cite` citation management package to using the [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package with the options `numbers` and `sort&compress`.

A side-benefit you'll get from using the `natbib` package is that, among all BibTeX-based citation management packages, it's most compatible with the hyperref package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{References.bib}
@misc{dummy1,author="A",title="X",year=3001}
@misc{dummy2,author="B",title="Y",year=3002}
@misc{dummy3,author="C",title="Z",year=3003}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\cite{dummy1,dummy2,dummy3}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, this works! Thanks man!
For the uninitiated: just replace 
\usepackage{cite} with 
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

Comment: As Mico has said, replacing \usepackage{cite}
by \usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib} fixes the issue.